# Google Sheets Add-on Triggers with 5-minute timers are not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, installation, spreadsheet

I have published an add on on Google Marketplace, it installs, and manually it performs all the tasks, but I need it to be able to use clock triggers that I have designed to be installed during the add-on installation. Triggers do not work for my add-on.
Here is the trigger function

```js
    //creates a trigger for function: setUpdateGradebookTrigger() 
    function setUpdateGradebookTrigger() {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('updateGradebookOnTriggers')
    .timeBased()
    .everyMinutes(5)
    .create();
    }

    // function: setUpdateGradebookTrigger() 
    function updateGradebookOnTriggers() {
    
      // add new courses to the gradebook
      addNewCoursesToGradebook() 
     
      if (!inTestFolder()) {
        Logger.log('Tests are Not in exams folder');
        updateTestScores();  // Runtime 3 min, 08 sec  
      } else {
        Logger.log('Tests are in exams folder')
      }
    
      var date = getLocalTime();
      var minute = date.getMinutes();
      var day = date.getDay();
      var hour = date.getHours();
      if (day == 6 && hour == 0 && minute < 5) {
        // save date as values
        saveDataAsValues();  // Runtime: 14 seconds
      } else {
          if (hour == 1) {
            if (minute < 5) {
              createAllProgressReportTemplates(); // Runtime: 0 min, 34 secs          
            } else if (minute < 10) {
              setAllFormulas();
            } else if (minute < 15) {
              updateSharedSpreadsheets();
            } 
          } else if (minute < 5) {
            updateNextCourse();     // Runtime: 2 min, 04 sec (29 students)
          } 
      }  
    
      // update recent test scores and worksheet grades
      updateTestsAndWorksheets();  // Runtime: 2 min, 02 sec
      setAllFormulas();
    }

// get local time

    function getLocalTime() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var local_time = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
      var now = new Date();
      var local_date = Utilities.formatDate(now, local_time, 'MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss');
    
      return local_date;
    }
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.
I solved the issue:
I was trying to install run triggers that run every 5-minutes. Google add-on published on Google Marketplace triggers run on 61 minutes (hourly).
When I changed them to .everyHours(2), they installed and worked fine.